# Ubuntu automatically startup after power returns

Tags: boot, 18.04

I use ubuntu desktop machine as server.

Is there a way (probably in boot) to automatically start-up when power returns (let's say power goes down, and after it returns I want ubuntu desktop machine to start-up automatically)?

Comment: It's a BIOS setting (not an Ubuntu setting). Either your BIOS has it...or not.

Comment: What starts now when you power on machine? Then what do you have to type to start Ubuntu?

Comment: I just want machine to startUp whenever it has electricity and is currently shut down.